# vexing parse in STL scott meyers

Tags: c++, stl, most-vexing-parse

I am reding about Item6 which is about most vexing parse in *Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library* by Scott Meyers.

```
ifstream dataFile("ints.dat");
list<int> data(istream_iterator<int>(dataFile), // warning! this doesn't do
               istream_iterator<int>()); // what you think it does
```

All of which is interesting (in its own twisted way), but it doesn't help us say what we want to say, which is that a list object should be initialized with the contents of a file. Now that we know what parse we have to defeat, that's easy to express. It's not legal to surround a formal parameter declaration with parentheses, but it is legal to sur-round an argument to a function call with parentheses, so by adding a pair of parentheses, we force compilers to see things our way:

```
list<int> data((istream_iterator<int>(dataFile)), // note new parens
                istream_iterator<int>0); // around first argument
                                         // to list's constructor
```

My question is What does author mean by following statement?
   "It's not legal to surround a formal parameter declaration with parentheses, but it is legal to sur-round an argument to a function call with parentheses"

Thanks

Comment: That book is somewhat aged. Nowadays you'd use uniform initialization to defeat that parse.

Comment: You cannot do `int foo((int a))`. but you can do `int foo((((42))));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does author mean by following statement? *It's not legal to surround a formal parameter declaration with parentheses, but it is legal to sur-round an argument to a function call with parentheses*

What Scott Meyers is saying, is that, by surrounding the argument to a function call with parentheses, it can only be a *function call* and **not** a *function declaration*, since the latter would be illegal (i.e.: the possibility of being a function declaration is ruled out).

Otherwise, if both were legal, it would be interpreted as a function declaration instead. This is because of C++'s *most vexing parse*: anything that can be interpreted as a declaration will be interpreted as a such.

---

As already suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570644/vexing-parse-in-stl-scott-meyers#comment82098675_47570644) by [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/), as of C++11, you can use *brace initialization* instead:

```
ifstream dataFile("ints.dat");
list<int> data{istream_iterator<int>(dataFile), istream_iterator<int>()};
```

`data` above won't be interpreted as a function declaration, since braces are not allowed in a function declaration.